# How to reset password via email using MVC approach?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

In my controller, a Login.php :

```
/*     * *RESET AND SEND PASSWORD TO REQUESTED EMAIL*** */

function reset_password() {
    $account_type = $this->input->post('account_type');
    if ($account_type == "") {
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    }
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $result = $this->email_model->password_reset_email($account_type, $email); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
    if ($result == true) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('password_sent'));
    } else if ($result == false) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message', get_phrase('account_not_found'));
    }

    redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
}
```

In my Email_model.php :

```
function account_opening_email($account_type = '', $email = '') 
{
  $system_name = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'system_name'))->row()->description;

    $email_msg = "Welcome to " . $system_name . "<br />";
    $email_msg .= "Your account type : " . $account_type . "<br />";
    $email_msg .= "Your login password : " . $this->db->get_where($account_type, array('email' => $email))->row()->password . "<br />";
    $email_msg .= "Login Here : " . base_url() . "<br />";

    $email_sub = "Account opening email";
    $email_to = $email;

    $this->do_email($email_msg, $email_sub, $email_to);
}

function password_reset_email($account_type = '', $email = '') {
    $query = $this->db->get_where($account_type, array('email' => $email));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $password = $query->row()->password;
        $email_msg = "Your account type is : " . $account_type . "<br />";
        $email_msg .= "Your password is : " . $password . "<br />";

        $email_sub = "Password reset request";
        $email_to = $email;
        $this->do_email($email_msg, $email_sub, $email_to);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/*     * *custom email sender*** */

function do_email($msg = NULL, $sub = NULL, $to = NULL, $from = NULL) {

    $config = array();
    $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['mailpath'] = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "localhost";
    $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $system_name = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'system_name'))->row()->description;
    if ($from == NULL)
        $from = $this->db->get_where('settings', array('type' => 'system_email'))->row()->description;

    $this->email->from($from, $system_name);
    $this->email->from($from, $system_name);
    $this->email->to($to);
    $this->email->subject($sub);

    $msg = $msg . "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><hr /><center><a>&copy; 2017 blablabla</a></center>";
    $this->email->message($msg);

    $this->email->send();

    //echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}

}
```

In View, a login.php :

resetting part only

```
<!-----------password reset form ------>

    <div class="modal fade" id="modal_ajax">
    <div class="modal-dialog" >
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo get_phrase('reset_password');?></h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" style="height:100px; overflow:auto;">

            <div class="modal-body">

        <?php echo form_open('Login/reset_password');?>
        <div class="col-sm-5"> 

            <select class="form-control" name="account_type"  style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">

                <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('account_type');?></option>

                <option value="doctor"><?php echo get_phrase('doctor');?></option>

                <option value="patient"><?php echo get_phrase('patient');?></option>

                <option value="nurse"><?php echo get_phrase('nurse');?></option>

                <option value="pharmacist"><?php echo get_phrase('pharmacist');?></option>

                <option value="laboratorist"><?php echo get_phrase('laboratorist');?></option>

                <option value="receptionist"><?php echo get_phrase('receptionist');?></option>

            </select>
            </div>

             <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="field-1" placeholder="Enter Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="Please enter a valid email" >
                    </div>

            <input type="submit" value="<?php echo get_phrase('reset');?>"  class="btn btn-blue btn-medium"/>

        <?php echo form_close();?>

      </div>
```

```
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure it out why it is not working, it just refreshing the page.
Plzz help me out on it

Comment: What errors are you getting in your logs?

Comment: Empty page means you are getting a server error from PHP. What is in your logs?

Comment: Run phpinfo(); and hit control+F and search for error_log. Look inside that file. You've got to learn how to use your tools. If a carpenter is complaining about nails not going into wood and unwilling to pickup a hammer on the ground, no one will take him seriously.

Comment: Sending passwords in plain text emails in a long way from secure